# Has the Bitcoin getblocktemplate response json changed? Where is the coinbasetxn now?

Tags: rpc, bitcoin, coinbase-api

When calling getblocktemplate for the bitcoin rpc, the json (dictionary) response that comes back no longer seems to have a 'coinbasetxn' key in it. Where is the coinbase transaction now?

Sample response to `getblocktemplate()`:

> {'height': 453825, 'mintime': 1487548277, 'version': 536870912,
>   'coinbasevalue': 1306788433, 'previousblockhash':
>   '0000000000000000019ca63484f8251b15647869d4c36ec5b201277f3e2aa70b',
>   'rules': ['csv'], 'sigoplimit': 20000, 'weightlimit': 4000000,
>   'mutable': ['time', 'transactions', 'prevblock'], 'target':
>   '0000000000000000027e93000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
>   'bits': '18027e93', 'longpollid':
>   '0000000000000000019ca63484f8251b15647869d4c36ec5b201277f3e2aa70b20632',
>   'vbrequired': 0, 'noncerange': '00000000ffffffff', 'curtime':
>   1487550914, 'coinbaseaux': {'flags': ''}, 'transactions': [{'depends':
>   [], 'data':
>   '0100000001fb5b6947704577fd09260adf7f80c92ada4776ca7674a5fb8af40df3c747293a010000006a473044022048aab0d8bd6c127696ce2cceb42693af2ae8eec561a33acf43577193070cd965022043667ae3c25661d251133b75fbefa8b9b5d3dddeedae028c90899c642f693479012103c7b4ed6b91df7eb7d2bd62a6257dd2e2fa79d07e81080b7e95bcd3d9e448f464feffffff02504b4500000000001976a914fd09ed8b3099ee1f67693c3c6c25ca7ecb150fcf88ac48c5374e000000001976a914a97d5d95cd416dc0f734cb028f0785a4f545cea988ac96ec0600',
>   'txid':
>   '2ed056bed0417623433d6b600dfb6afcebb8c22b1f42b6e776cf8263289fb5ac',
>   'sigops': 2, 'weight': 900, 'fee': 204345, 'hash':
>   '2ed056bed0417623433d6b600dfb6afcebb8c22b1f42b6e776cf8263289fb5ac'},
>   {'depends': [], 'data':
>   '01000000011e7d9c88fe30a4c9fa1ec229e7c11704ec0185e36...... (...rest of
>   transactions...)

Comment: Is it possibly just the first transaction in the 'transactions' list?  Can someone confirm for me?

Answer (score 1):

bitcoin core doesn't provide a coinbasetxn in the block template; it's the pool software that does that. if you're coding mining software to connect directly to bitcoind without using a pool, you'll need to generate the coinbase transaction yourself.

Answer (score -2):

Confirmed that it is the first transaction of the transaction list.  Can close this question (no longer need help).  Thank you.

Comment: I think it is not correct, can anyone please confirm this?

Comment: incorrect. a coinbase transaction has no inputs. https://blockchain.info/tx/2ed056bed0417623433d6b600dfb6afcebb8c22b1f42b6e776cf8263289fb5ac